# How to get index value of a link with a specific class using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, indexing, hyperlink

I have about 20 links with a specific class for links I want to target. If the 10th link is clicked, how can I get it's index value (I need "10" to be returned)?

I am using plain JavaScript so no jQuery!

Comment: Unless you are willing to write a lot of javascript you are going to have to use some library. Why not jQuery? The ultimate getbyclassname is 78 lines. No sense in redoing work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop throught the elements, [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MZURB/1/)

```
function linkOnClick(el) {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] == el) {
            alert(i); // index of element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certain browsers and versions do not support getElementByClassName so you would need to implement a custom written one for compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a getElementsByClassName function.  Latest versions of Firefox, Safari and Opera support this but if you want ultimate cross-browser compatibility, I would recommend this function found at: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Then you would loop through the returned elements in a function for the onclick attribute and test if the index matches the index required which you would pass through as a parameter

**Edit:**  Exactly as written in the answer by [IAbstractDownvoteFactor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724626/iabstractdownvotefactory)